# visual studio 2013 truncates returned pointer value in x64

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, compilation, 64-bit

I try to compile wingraphviz for x64 (it's an old, unmaintained project), and ran into a very strange problem :

There's a call to `getDefaultFont()` that looks like this :

```
const char* def = getDefaultFont();
Deffontname = late_nnstring(g->proto->n,N_fontname,def);
```

(original code did the call inside function call, but I extracted it for understanding)

the `getDefaultFont` function is very simple, and returns a string litteral based on current charset :

```
const char * getDefaultFont() {
    switch(DOT_CODEPAGE) {

            case CP_KOREAN:
            return CP_949_DEFAULTFONT;
            break;
[...]

            default:
            return DEFAULT_FONTNAME;
            break;
    }
}
```

with `DEFAULT_FONTNAME` & others defined in a header file :

```
#define     DEFAULT_FONTNAME    "Times New Roman"
```

I changed the return to `{ const char* r = DEFAULT_FONTNAME; return r; }` to see the value while debugging: r is correct at return instruction.

But when the debugger returns to caller function, `def` points to invalid memory.

I ran the debugger in assembly mode, and see that :

```
    const char* def = getDefaultFont();
000007FEDA1244FE  call        getDefaultFont (07FEDA1291A0h)  
000007FEDA124503  cdqe  
000007FEDA124505  mov         qword ptr [def],rax
```

after the `call` instruction, RAX contains the correct value, a pointer to  .data : RAX = 000007FEDA0C9A20 
but the next instruction, `cqde` "Convert dword (eax) to qword (rax)." destroy the 4 higher bytes, and now RAX = FFFFFFFFDA0C9A20. Then the third stores the truncated value on stack.

After that, late_nnstring() tries to de-reference the corrupted pointer and crashes...

Do you know why VS inserts this `cqde` instruction ?
All theses functions are in .c files under the same project.

I've implemented a workaround, using strdup() to return low-memory addresses, but it's not safe (maybe heap can use memory after 4G?) (and there my be some other cases I did not find while testing that will crash when using the library)

I published the files here : https://gitlab.com/data-public/wingraphviz

especially :

- caller at https://gitlab.com/data-public/wingraphviz/blob/97085eeb6e9356c7784965c5a43757d8db3fec41/dependencies/graphviz-1.8.10/dotneato/common/emit.c#L842
- getDefaultFont at https://gitlab.com/data-public/wingraphviz/blob/97085eeb6e9356c7784965c5a43757d8db3fec41/dependencies/graphviz-1.8.10/dotneato/common/utils.c#L111
- constant defines at https://gitlab.com/data-public/wingraphviz/blob/97085eeb6e9356c7784965c5a43757d8db3fec41/dependencies/graphviz-1.8.10/dotneato/common/const.h#L49

Comment: The gitlab project was misconfigured, it's public now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your links require some account I don’t have.

You likely failed to include the header declaring that function, or messed up with headers order. [Here’s more info](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0033/) why C compiler inserts `cdqe`.

P.S. Great example why you should read, and fix, compiler warnings.

**Update:** If you have circular dependency problem and can’t just include utils.h, a quick workaround is declare `const char * getDefaultFont();` in emit.c before you call that function.

Comment: You're right. Thanks. Missed the warning in the "too many warnings int this legacy code" output ... :/